# How To restrict DDL access to a sql server 2008 login

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to restrict the DDL access to SQL server login, if not possible how to restrict DDL to a particular user

Thank you

Comment: How does this login have rights to execute DDL?

Comment: What access exactly are you trying to restrict? DDL can cover a wide gamut of things. Prevent tables changes? Proc changes? Prevent viewing schema?